# JavaScript document.referrer

Tags: javascript

I've got two webpages one

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p><a href="page2.html">Link</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the second page.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write(document.referrer);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The second page is always blank, it doesn't seem to be picking up the referrer, any idea's why?

Comment: are these files hosted online or running off your local machine?

Comment: What browser are you using? Where and how are you hosting those pages?

Answer (score 9):

In IE, `document.referrer` works only for `http://` resources, not `https://` and `file://` ones. Maybe that is your problem.

**Edit:** There are [even more cases](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2008/11/bug-421-ie-fails-to-pass-http-referer.html) in which IE doesn't pass it on.

Comment: That is almost certainly the problem as I'm testing locally and when I tried it on the server it's a https:// . Best look into query strings in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Actually document.referrer which you used will return requesting page URL for all browsers except for Internet Explorer., it actually returns null in the IE.