# JavaScript Redirect: Problem with Referer Header

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-analytics, http-referer

Somebody follows a blog link(say http://blog) to come to my site (say http://mysite/a.php).

So now she is on page http://mysite/a.php and referer is set to http://blog

Now  there is JavaScript on the page http://mysite/a.php which does the following redirection:

```
    document.location = "http://mysite/b.php;
    //This is executed before any Google Analytics script.
```

Now in the request to http://mysite/b.php, referer is set as http://mysite/a.php.
Because of which (I think so) my Google Analytics is showing all the traffic coming from http://mysite/a.php.

Suggest a solution please.
Note: JavaScript redirection is critical, can't get rid of it.
Also I tried sending 302 code from server, but no success.

Comment: What about redirecting after Google Analytics?

Comment: Yes. I thought about it. But wanted to avoid that because that will delay the redirection, if GA takes time.

Comment: Varun, have either of the answers helped clarify your problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Edit: New, recommended way

Google Analytics now has a special URL parameter, `utm_referrer`, where you can pass the referer to the page you're redirecting to; doing so will simulate the same behavior as below without any need to mess with cookies or functions.

In your example, you'd make your code say:

```
 document.location = "http://mysite/b.php?utm_referrer=" + encodeURIComponent(location.href); ;
```

---

### Old, harder but functional way

Google Analytics has a function called [setRefererOverride()](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiCampaignTracking.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setReferrerOverride). If you set it, it will override the referrer value that it tracks to whatever value you set.

The [best way to do this](http://www.prusak.com/google-analytics-referrer-override/) is to, prior to the redirect, store the real referrer in a cookie, like so:

```
document.cookie = "realreferrer="+encodeURIComponent(document.referrer)+"; path=/";
```

Then, read the cookie value on the page. If the cookie is set, call that function before your pageview.

```
var realreferrer = readCookie("realreferrer"); //using a readCookie function of some kind
if (realreferrer) {
 _gaq.push(['_setReferrerOverride', realreferrer ]);
            //if using the old code, use pageTracker._setReferrerOverride(realreferrer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest (and maybe only) way would be to trigger a GA count in `a.php` before doing the redirection.

If that's not an option, the only way I can see to keep the referrer alive is

```
document.location = "http://mysite/b.php?referrer="+
                    encodeURIComponent(document.referrer);
```

(will [not work in IE under some circumstances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145534/javascript-document-referrer))

But that will still not tell GA to set the referrer accordingly - you would to have to force it upon Google Analytics when counting. I don't know whether that is possible.

Comment: Regarding the first option: That will delay the redirection, if GA takes time. Not sure abouth secound option though. Will check

Comment: @Varun I see your point, but I'm pretty sure the first option is the only really good one.

Comment: This is problematic for 2 reasons, but can be (mostly) fixed. **1.** GA doesn't have a callback, so there's no way to be sure of how long you should wait for the pageview to track. You guess too short, you miss traffic. You guess too long, you frustrate users. **2**. You'll pollute the URLs by adding the referrer into the URL, so you'd need to be sure to remove that by filter. But, if OP does choose to do it this way, he can use setReferrerOverride to get it to work.