# Detecting whether current link is first for page in browser history

Tags: javascript, gwt, navigation, back-button, browser-history

Is it possible to reliably check (cross-browser, of course) whether the page that the user is currently viewing in the browser is the first in the history stack for my site, i.e., whether a click on "back" would take the user to another page of my site or whether it would take him/her away from my site?

Some examples (true=current page is first, i.e. "back" would leave site):

1. User first opens page of site via bookmark: **true** ("back" would go off-site to whatever page was opened before).
2. User then clicks on link to navigate to another page on my site: **false** ("back" would not go off-site, but back to the page opened in (1.)).
3. User clicks the original bookmark again and lands again on the first page: **false** ("back" would go to page opened in (2.)).
4. User clicks "back" twice to return to page opened in (1.): **true** (another "back" would now go off-site again).

Number (1.) and (2.) are easy to detect, but (3.) and (4.) pose my problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can check the referrer URL before the back operation happens would solve this issue.

If the referrer URL is null disable the back button

Comment: That would have been very nice and clean, but unfortunately FireFox and Chrome always give me an empty string, independent of where I came from... I forgot to mention: I'm trying to do this client-side in JavaScript. I can't rely on a page-load to hit my server.

Comment: document.referrer is giving the correct value for me in FireFox and Chrom. How are you checking the referrer ?

Comment: I've tried the pure JavaScript `window.alert(document.referrer)` and calling `Document.get().getReferrer()` from GWT (which is what i'm actually using to build my page). In both cases I get empty strings. And it seems like I'm not the only one having this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145534/javascript-document-referrer . And even if I can make it work reliably in some cases, unfortunately I need it to work in all cases...

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand GWT History Mechanism and Activites and Places to achieve this.

Try these [History](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory?hl=en) and [Activities and Places](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces) for starters

Comment: :) That's exactly what I'm working with and unfortunately neither the pure History, nor the Activities and Places framework covers this scenario. Or maybe I'm missing something? Do you have a move detailed link that I may have missed?